# how to open a file (ie. .txt file) in C++ (kinda like double clicking it in windows)?

Tags: c++, windows, file, io

I'm wondering how I can open a file literally in C++ (like double clicking it)?

Comment: Are you asking about the ability to automate keyboard/mouse like in the Java Robot class?

Comment: ack..didn't know how to describe properly.. like when you double click a file in windows, how to do that in code?

I'm looking for something like process.start("blabla.txt") in .NET

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Provided you have the ".txt" extension registered (and text files should be associated with Notepad in a default installation, or something else if you've changed it from Explorer - you'd have to work pretty hard to disassociate them), Windows will open it for you without you having to specify the executable name:

```
ShellExecute (hwnd,"open","c:\\x.txt",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
```

or, for a web page in your browser of choice:

```
ShellExecute (hwnd,"open","http://www.microsoft.com",NULL,NULL,SW_SHOW);
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean like open explorer?
How about using

```
system("explorer.exe file.to.open");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) function with the "open" operation.

Answer (score 2):

Use ShellExecute with the "open" verb.
See [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/newbiespawn.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

easy way: system("notepad.exe [location to file]");